# My uncle's impossible yet clean enigma 9+5=2

Tags: lateral-thinking

My uncle gave me the puzzle:

> 9+5=2
> Quelle est la réponse ?

That translates to

> 9+5=2
> What is the answer?

I don't know the answer yet. I have look into matchsticks without success but it could be something else. Plus there is no information about the number of matchsticks one should move...

As he's French and he doesn't speak English, I do not exclude you should understand French, and if so, I apologize for that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be something simple as

> 9am + 5 hours = 2pm?

i.e.

> [arithmetic modulo 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), also known as 'Clock arithmetic'?

Comment: Definetely +1, I'm waiting for his answer, to know if I'll select yours

Comment: Alright, he told me: "I never knew the answer, someone gave it to me more than 20 years ago, this solution is very well". Looks like you are a 20 years chain breaker :p