# Matchsticks 9 + 9 = 8

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, matches

You are given the wrong equation (made out of matchsticks) 9 + 9 = 8 and you can move **at most** 3 matches. Your aim is to find all possible correct equations. Selected answer will be one that discovers most correct equations first.

[image]

Don't forget the [lateral thinking] tag!

Comment: Since there's a lateral-thinking tag, would you accept answers that use matches and not pen markings?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think I would accept both!

Comment: I don't think there is a correct answer to "all correct equations", as there is too many ways to interpret the question with "lateral thinking" stipulations.
I also don't think it makes a particular clever puzzle, as you can just take a random match stick equation and ask people to find different solutions.

Comment: This is an "open-ended" puzzle in exactly the way described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles); it is a *game* where people compete to give as many answers as possible, not a *puzzle* with a definitive solution. For this reason, it is off-topic for our site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $-2 + 8 = 6$ (3 moved)
> $3^1 + 3^1 = 6^1$ (3 moved)
> $3^1 + 5^1 = 8$ (2 moved)
> $8 - 8 = 0$ (2 moved)

Since it's "lateral"

> Moving matches out of view, i.e. re-moving
> $0 + 0 = 0$ (2 moved, 1 removed)
> $0 + 9 = 9$ (1 moved, 1 removed)
> $2 + 6 = 8$ (2 moved, 1 removed)
> $3 + 3 = 6$ (3 removed)
> $3 + 5 = 8$ (2 removed)
> $3 + 6 = 9$ (1 moved, 2 removed)
> $5 + 5 = 10$ (2 moved, 1 removed)
> $6 + 3 = 9$ (1 moved, 2 removed)
> $9 + 0 = 9$ (1 moved, 1 removed)
> $9 - 0 = 9$ (1 moved, 2 removed)
> $9 - 9 = 0$ (2 removed)

Comment: No actually, this is part of the puzzle. You are on the way to be selected answer ;) I confounded with something else. I count 5 equations in your answer up to now ;)

Comment: OK. Hidden again.

Answer (score 8):

A 'lateral' answer:

> Remove a match from the second nine and two from the eight to get [9+5=2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98155/my-uncles-impossible-yet-clean-enigma-95-2), apparently true!

Comment: Haha, I didn't expect someone to catch it that fast!

Answer (score 5):

The classical

> use any match to turn the $=$ into $\neq$

Comment: One might argue that it is an inequality and not an equation. One might...

Comment: @JoelRondeau you are right, I didn't notice that we had to produce **equations**

Comment: I wouldn't remove the answer, though. If you do someone else will just add it and we'll go through all this over again. In fact, +1.

Answer (score 3):

two more possibilities

> -9 + 9 = 0 or +9-9=0: move middle line of 8 to form -, (move one stick from plus to form plus on the left)
>
> 9 + 6 = 15 or 6+9=15: move two sticks from 8 to form 15, move one stick from 9 to form 6

Answer (score 3):

Another "lateral"

> Rotate the equation 180 degrees. Then remove two matches from the 8, to turn it into 12.
>  12 = 6 + 6

Answer (score 2):

I can do it using 2 matches:

> 8-0=8

Solution:

> Move the up-ward facing matchstick from the plus to the 9 (makes it 8) then move the middle matchstick from the second 9 to the bottom to make it a 0

Comment: Correct! Can you find the other correct equations?

Answer (score 2):

*Removing* 3 matches gives the following example of [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking):

> [`5+5=A`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
>  `{   _     _     _   }`
>  `{  │_  + │_  = │_│  }`
>  `{   _│    _│   │ │  }`

*Moving* 2 matches gives this:

> 9+9=18
>  `{   _     _       _   }`
>  `{  │_│ + │_│ = │ │_│  }`
>  `{    │     │   │ │_│  }`

And, combining the two methods:

> 9+9=12 (base 16)
>  `{   _     _       _   }`
>  `{  │_│ + │_│ = │  _│  }`
>  `{   _│    _│   │ │_   }`

Comment: I'd looked for a way of moving matchsticks to get hex addition, I did not look for a way to remove matchsticks to get hex addition.

Answer (score 1):

Another 'lateral' one:

> 3 + 5 == 8 *(moving 2 matchsticks to turn it into a programming-style equation)*

Answer (score 1):

### 4+

Hmm...

> $9+9 > 8$ (move $=$ so it is $>$)

> $8 - 0=8$ (move vertical line in plus to make 9 into 8, turn 9 into 0 by moving middle line)

> $9-9 ≠ 8$ (move plus sign to make not equals)

> $9+9≠0$ (move 8's middle to make ≠)

> You can make so many solutions just by changing the sign in the middle!*

Contributed by friends:

> $-9+9=0$ (move middle of 8 to before first 9 to make -9)
>  $5+3=8$ (remove to make 9s into 5 and 3)

<sup>*but I'm too lazy</sup>

Comment: I want to put each answer on a separate line within the spoiler quote, but when I try the spoiler turns into a normal block quote. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! That is a nice first answer and I helped you a little on the formatting ;) you get my upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Another lateral-thinking answer:

> Don't move any matches at all. $9+9=8$ [is valid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.